# Expression conversion while migrating from crystal report to jasper report

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports, migration

I am developing jasper report for available crystal report. In crystal report I have one formula field which has following variable expression:

```
IF {Command.PAYMENTS}=0 THEN 0
ELSE
(sum({Command.IVE_BEFORE_FFP})/sum({Command.PAYMENTS}))*100
```

In jasper I want to create same variable. I know how to take sum of a column using variable.

So while converting above expression can I use following way? I don't have data to test my results that's why I am asking this question here.

```
 var1 :  test1
 <variable name="test1" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
      <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{IVE_BEFORE_FFP}]]></variableExpression>
 </variable>


  var2:  test2
  <variable name="test2" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Sum">
      <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{PAYMENTS}]]></variableExpression>
 </variable>
```

And final expression for replacing above expression from crystal report:

```
 $F{PAYMENTS} == 0 ? 0: $V{test1}/$V{test2}*100
```

so will they give same results?

This variable is used in group footer and summary band? So I am confused weather it will give same results as crystal gives.

Am I following correct way or is there any way to do this?

Comment: Seems good to me, your resetType since you have not indicated it is report (so it will sum on all records), as class indication I would use same as the fields. You can use the variable where ever you like, if you have groups (and like to sum only the sub group you need to use the resetType)

Comment: What if I want to use same variable in summary band and group footer? If i am setting reset type as group then inside group footer its giving correct count but in summary band it's showing count of last group instead of showing sum of column? What is the solution for this? And thanks for your response :)

Comment: Yes it will show last group count in summary band... the solution is to make another variable... with reset type Report and use this in summary band

Comment: @PetterFriberg Thanks for sharing some knowledge :)

Comment: My pleasure, when all is ok, remember to fill in the answer and check it solved... If you comment here (i will see that you answered) and I will upvote your answer, if it is nice. My mission is closing questions ; ), so that other can use in the future...